# How to use getOrElse in status.in() of Gatling?

Tags: scala, gatling

I have a method `getUsers()` with an optional parameter `stat`, this parameter represents a **single** status code. When the parameter `stat` is not provided I want the function to check against **multiple** status codes using `getOrElse`. This is my current code but does not work:

```
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._
import scala.concurrent.duration._

class UnitTestActions {

    def getUsers(stat: Option[Int]) = {
        exec(http("[GET] /users")
            .get("/users")
            .check(status.in(stat getOrElse(Seq(200, 405)))))
    }

}
```

The following works partially:

```
check(status.in(stat getOrElse 200, 405))
```

When `stat` is **not** provided it checks against 200 and 405, which is good.
But when `stat` is provided it checks against `stat` **and** 405, which is no the desired outcome.

I've tried various things but each time I get the error `cannot be applied to (Any)`. Can somebody assist me?

Comment: Make stat `Seq[Int]`?

Comment: Then I get: `value getOrElse is not a member of Seq[Int]`. What value should I provide for `getOrElse`?

Comment: Sorry, I meant map it to same type: `stat.map(s => Seq(s)).getOrElse(default)` :D Or you could pass `stat: Option[Seq[Int]]` which would be more flexible

Comment: Thank you very much, changing `Option[Int]` to `Option[Seq[Int]]` did the trick! I'd accept your answer if you would post one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Option`'s `getOrElse` method has the following signature:

```
final def getOrElse[B >: A](default: ⇒ B): B
```

It expects the same type or it's supertype. So, here you can map your optional `Int` you pass to a `Seq[Int]` and do this:

```
stat.map(s => Seq(s)).getOrElse(defaults)
```

---

Or you can pass an `Option[Seq[Int]]` and later you can pass multiple statuses as default:

```
def getUsers(stat: Option[Seq[Int]])
```

Here, your code should wok unchanged.